# Regular expression for multiple words on Google forms validation

Tags: google-forms

Simply I would like to add some answers that can't be answered by the submitter or user
I want a Regular expression for multiple words on Google forms validation

How to write a regular expression or a pattern for that matter

I've tried that

```
(Student Name 1|Student Name 2|Student Name 3)
```

With and without brackets 
And the response just prevent the whole string like it isn't a regular expression

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you looking for a regular expression that will match this format, `("Student Name 1"|"Student Name 2"|"Student Name 3")`?

Comment: I want to add multiple words to use them in the validation

Comment: I just tested your regex in a short answer question and it seems to work fine for me. Just make sure the validation type is "Regex" and the second option is set to "Matches".

Comment: I was using text instead of regular expression